# pst-circ: Prevent Rotation of Part of the Symbol

Tags: pstricks, pst-circ

I am using pst-circ to draw a circuit. For this I want to draw a voltmeter, so I use `newCircDipole` to define a new element (MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\newCircDipole{pscircmeter}
\makeatletter
\def\pst@draw@pscircmeter{%
    \pnode(-0.3,0){dipole@1}
    \pnode(0.3,0){dipole@2}
    \psline[fillstyle=none,linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth,arrowinset=0]{->}%
        (-0.4,-0.4)(0.45,0.45)
    \pscircle[linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid](0,0){0.3}
}
\makeatother
\def\voltmeter{\pscircmeter[labeloffset=0]}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pnodes(0,-1){A}(0,1){B}
    \voltmeter(B)(A){V}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

and then use it as `\voltmeter(A)(B){V}`. Clearly I am going for this:

[image: circuit voltmeter]

My question is about rotating this construct. If the nodes A and B are on top of each other, the `pscircmeter` gets rotated with the arrow, see the MWE above. However, I want to retain the direction of the arrow (down-left to top-right) similar to the correct alignment of the text label (up).

---

I realise there might be cases where the wire and the arrow align, but I am willing to risk that.

---

While we are at it: Is it possible to change the default label to `V` so that I can use it as `\voltmeter(A)(B){}` an still get the `V` printed?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\newCircDipole{pscircmeter}
\makeatletter
\def\pst@draw@pscircmeter{%
    \pnode(-0.3,0){dipole@1}
    \pnode(0.3,0){dipole@2}
    \pscircle[linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth,fillstyle=solid](0,0){0.3}
}
\makeatother
\def\voltmeter{%      
    \psline[linewidth=1.5\pslinewidth,arrowinset=0]{->}(-0.4,-0.4)(0.45,0.45)
    \pscircmeter[labeloffset=0]}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1)
    \pnodes(0,-1){A}(0,1){B}
    \voltmeter(B)(A){V}
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-1,-1)(1,1)
  \pnodes(-1,0){A}(1,0){B}
  \voltmeter(B)(A){V}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Drawing the label V by default is possible but not really easy to solve.

Comment: Nice! It does fail, however, if I attempt to use the `parallel` option. (So for my ammeter this will work perfectly.)